# Strange things on WolframAlpha: derivation, modulo and doubling result

Tags: derivatives, modular-arithmetic, wolfram-alpha

I asked WA what is the derivative of $\frac1{\cos((x \bmod \pi/2)-\pi/4))}$ equal to for $x=0$.
A very strange result came out. The exact result is $-\sqrt2 \mathsf{Mod}^{(1,0)}(0,\frac\pi2)$, clicking on *Approximate form* shows cca. 79.
This number was not what I expected so I clicked on *More digits* and the number doubled! Now it was about 316! (*Note: that's **not** a factorial*)
The result doubles every time I click on *More digits*, up to cca. 1240.

Link to WA: http://goo.gl/ntJ774

What's the meaning of $\mathsf{Mod}^{(1,0)}$ and is this behaviour correct?

Comment: It's the partial derivative of the Mod relation with respect to its first slot.  If it existed, that derivative would be one, but $\mathrm{Mod}(x,\pi/2)$ is discontinuous at $0$.  The galloping values under repeated approximation expansion is quite weird.

Comment: @EricTowers Like all discrete functions in Mathematica, there is no symbolic derivative for `Mod`. When asked to compute a numerical value of derivative for such a function, Mathematica falls back to numerical estimates. The "galloping values" arise from a finer discretization used for increased precision.